# How to get client machine name during login. C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, client, hostname

I tried this [link in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160991/how-to-get-client-machine-name-in-asp-net-c) but not getting the client's name.

```
clientHostName = clientIpAddress = string.Empty;
try
    {
         clientIpAddress = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientIpAddress))
         {
             clientIpAddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
         }
                
         System.Net.IPAddress myIP = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(clientIpAddress);
         System.Net.IPHostEntry GetIPHost = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(myIP);

         clientHostName = GetIPHost.HostName; // Working in dev environment. Moving to QA env this is returning null
        }
        catch { }
```

Comment: What are you getting with this code? Any error!

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya. In the dev environment I am getting machine name. Moving to QA env this is returning null

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [blowdarts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6161635/11373183) answer in the post you linked. It is not possible to get the machine name of remote machines this way. If you are in control of the client application you may try to make the client explicitly send it's machine name instead.